# Drop down menu, directing (depending on answer) to next drop down?

Tags: javascript, menu

Below is what I currently have. I am now looking to be able to: When they click on artist one it will then take them to another drop down menu where there will be more options about Artist One. And the same if they chose Artist Two etc. Instead of just having an alert.

How would I go about that?
Thank you :)

```
<form>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="void">Choose your answer</option>
        <option value="artistOne">One</option>
        <option value="artistTwo">Two</option>
        <option value="artistThree">Three</option>
    </select>
</form>

<button id="button" onclick="artist();" type="button">Confirm</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function artist() {

    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var artist = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    if(artist == "artistOne"){
        alert("You have chosen Artist One!"); 
    }
    else if (artist == "artistTwo"){
        alert("You have chosen Artist Two!");
    }
}
```

Comment: is the other select somewhere or should it be dynamically created?

Comment: dynamically I believe, though I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
function artist() {    
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var artist = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var newSelectContainer = document.getElementById("artistDetails");

    if(artist == "artistOne"){
        createArtistSelect(newSelectContainer, ["Artist Detail 1", "Artist Detail 2", "Artist Detail 3"]);
    }
    else if (artist == "artistTwo"){
        createArtistSelect(newSelectContainer, ["Artist2 Detail 1", "Artist2 Detail 2"]);
    }
}  

function createArtistSelect(elem, options){
    //Create and append select list
    var dynamicSelect = document.getElementById("dynamicSelect");
    if(dynamicSelect)
      dynamicSelect.outerHTML = "";
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.id = "dynamicSelect";
    elem.appendChild(selectList);

    //Create and append the options
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = options[i];
        option.text = options[i];
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

If you change your javascript code to this you will generate a drop down menu with the passed options.

You need to change a bit your html:

```
<form>
    <div id="artistDetails">
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="void">Choose your answer</option>
        <option value="artistOne">One</option>
        <option value="artistTwo">Two</option>
        <option value="artistThree">Three</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</form>

<button id="button" onclick="artist();" type="button">Confirm</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that is called on the onChange of the select (you can change it to be on the onClick of the input)

```
var details1 = ["1-1", "1-2", "1-3"];
var details2 = ["2-1", "2-2", "2-3", "2-4"];
var details3 = ["3-1", "3-2"];


function CreateCmb(artist) {
    var cmbDetails = document.getElementById('cmbDetails');

    if (cmbDetails !== null) {
        while (cmbDetails.options.length > 0)
        cmbDetails.remove(0);
    } else {
        cmbDetails = document.createElement("select");
        cmbDetails.id = "cmbDetails";
        body.appendChild(cmbDetails);
    }

    var currentDetails = [];
    if (artist === "artistOne") currentDetails = details1;
    else if (artist === "artistTwo") currentDetails = details2;
    else if (artist === "artistThree") currentDetails = details3;

    for (var i = 0; i < currentDetails.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = currentDetails[i];
        option.value = currentDetails[i];
        cmbDetails.appendChild(option);
    }

}
```

How it works:

First it get the dynamic select, then check if he is NOT null (is created). If this is the case, it delete all the option. If the select is null (not yet created), it create it and place it in the body.

Then it check wich details he need to show (the if else if block).

To finish, I looped the details and create the new options.

The nice part about this is that you will always have only one dynamic select because if he already exist, he reuse it ! That allow you to manually create and place it somewhere and he will use it if he have the correct id (in this case 'cmbDetails')

[See this FIDDLE for an example !](http://jsfiddle.net/VwN4D/)